# Gmail API для корпоративной почты

Tags: google-api, gmail

Есть ли возможность использовать Gmail API для отправки почты с корпоративных e-mail?
Нет ли ограничений на отправку вложений (attachment) с сервера сайта?

Answer (score 3):

**2000** (**500** для пробных аккаунтов)
вот пруф

> https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=ru

по поводу api уточните. возможно Вы имели ввиду отправку по средствами *google smtp*?

**Обновление**

Возможно Вы видели это сообщение в офф доках?

> **Note: The Gmail API should not be used to replace IMAP for full-fledged email client access. Instead, see IMAP and SMTP.**

Тут говорится если Вы планируете только отправку то смотрите в сторону smpt и imap, хотя я не знаю Ваших потребностей и не так хорош в языках.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/

Comment: имею в виду отправку сообщений по средствам rest api

Comment: для моих целей подходит именно gmail api (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending), просто я опасаюсь, что его нельзя будет использовать для корпоративной почты, поэтому решил спросить - вдруг кто сталкивался